# Combining lmodern, charter and sourcecodepro fonts

Tags: fonts, latin-modern

I know, usually you should avoid many different fonts but I'd be happy with the following configuration:

- Title, Chapter, Section, ... and Description labels should use **bold Latin Modern Sans Serif**
- Text should use font from `charter` package
- and for teletype fonts I'd like to use Source Code Pro. (at least for listings in `lstlisting` environment)

Currently I use the following configuration:

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,                   % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=semi,               % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,                  % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=half-,              % spacing value / method for paragraphs
%   chapterprefix=true,         % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                       % font size
    headings=normal,            % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,         % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,               % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,               % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,        % display table captions above the float env
    draft=true,             % value for draft version
    dvipsnames
]{scrbook}%

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{charter}
%\usepackage[semibold, extralight]{sourcecodepro}
% headings

\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{black}\huge\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont} % for chapter entries
\setkomafont{section}{\color{black}\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont} % for section entries
\setkomafont{subsection}{\color{black}\Large\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont} % for section entries
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\color{black}\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont\small\bfseries}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\lstset{    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
%   commentstyle=\slshape,
%   identifierstyle=\mdseries,
}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext
\section{First Section}
\blindtext
\subsection{First Subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\blindtext
\paragraph{First Paragraph}
\Blindtext

\begin{lstlisting}
And here I'd like to see Source Code Pro
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

When I disable `sourcecodepro` then everything looks as expected except the teletype fonts but when I include `sourcecodepro` then headlines and description labels  aren't bold anymore, they are very thin.

[image: No Source Code Pro but bold headlines]
[image: Source Code Pro but thin headlines]

I want to have both, **bold headlines** and `source code pro`.

Comment: Where is the sense of using option `extralight` if you do not want thin characters? However, I cannot see any problem with the description environment. Make a _complete_ example.

Comment: extra light is related to source code pro. The headings are very thin and they shouldn't be in source code pro but in Latin Modern Sans Serif.

Comment: I have no headers in sourcecodepro! `while true { working example }`...

Comment: Me too. But that's not the point. `repeat { read again } until understood` The headlines are in lmodern. But they aren't bold anymore when I enable source code pro. I'm working on a small example but I didn't want to post my entire masters thesis here as you might understand

Comment: @mr.VVoo I get boldface headlines.

Comment: @Herbert so i updated to a full example

Comment: @egreg When you get bold headlines do you ALSO get Source code Pro? I want both but I either get **bold** headlines or `source code pro`

Comment: @mr.VVoo If I uncomment the call to `sourcecodepro`, I get the same exact output, only with Source Code Pro for the listing. Can you check what version of `sourcecodepro.sty` you have? Look in the `.log` file for something like `sourcecodepro 2014/07/28 v2.3 Adobe's Source Code Pro typeface` and report the date you get.

Comment: Indeed it seems that I use an old one `Package: sourcecodepro 2013/09/23 v2.2 Adobe's Source Code Pro typeface` although I just updated to TexLive 2014 a couple of day ago.

Comment: @egreg That wasn't obviously but updating source code pro solved the problem. If you post your answer I'll mark it. Thx!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to outdated software